# Viewing LCOV file in Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, linux, unit-testing, lcov

Background: I have used JsTestDriverCoverage and generated a test coverage report for my Javascript unit tests.  However it is in LCOV format.  As a Windows user running on Windows 2003, I can't just read the file since its perl/lunix friendly.

Question: are there any ways to either convert the file to a more readable format (using command line), or using other applications to read the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use genhtml to convert it to a set of HTML files.
http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/genhtml.1.php

Comment: Doesn't genhtml runs on linux environment?  I needed to run/get the lcov format report in Windows environment. Thanks.

Comment: genhtml is just a perl script. As a quick experiment, I took an lcov file generated from a Linux app (I only use lcov on Linux) and ran it through genhtml on Windows (Cygwin). It ran ok but only if I turned off source-code highlighting (--no-source). Might work ok if your source is on Windows too? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816981/

Answer (score 2):

There is a genhtml port for windows here: http://code.google.com/p/jgenhtml/.

It's specifically designed to run cross platform - no problems with backslashes in the paths etc.