# Any way to get code coverage metrics from Catch C++ tests in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, code-coverage, visual-studio-2017, catch-unit-test

I have C++ project in VS 2017 with some [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md) tests in it. 
But I am not able to figure out how to get the test coverage metrics.

Although I prefer native VS solution I am happy to use VS extensions of necessary, but from what I can [see](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Unit_Testing_in_CPP.html) ReSharper does not support it:

> You are right, neither profiling nor coverage are supported for C++

Comment: This might be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042/how-can-i-measure-cppunit-test-coverage-on-win32-and-unix), since measuring coverage in C++ is a problem independent of the test framework. EDIT: Nevermind, the question and answers are quite 'ancient'

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Visual Studio provides coverage metrics with its profiling tools already. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jsocha/2011/08/16/capturing-c-code-coverage-with-visual-c/) for details